# HBase OutOfOrderScannerNextException on using filter on scan

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am getting the follwing exception while using filters

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Failed after retry of OutOfOrderScannerNextException: was there a rpc timeout?
```

If i remove filter then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This relates to the nature of the filter you are using. If `ValueFilter` is used on a table with large number of records, it takes time at the scanner and causes timeout for the client.

You can try increasing the default RPC timeout value from 60000 (1minute) to a larger value in `hbase-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>180000</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I've already increased it, current config is
`<property>
<name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
<value>300000</value>
<source>hbase-site.xml</source>
</property>`

Comment: Sorry it is supposed to be 30minutes. `1800000`. And is caching enabled in your code?

Comment: Testted with `1800000` still not working. I've also tested with `scan.setCacheBlocks(false);` but still same problem

Comment: What is the cachesize given for `scan.setCaching(size)`

Comment: Not set. may be it will be default one because of not setting it.

Comment: Can you set that to a greater value (default is 1) and try scanning

Comment: Did but no luck. I truncated the table then populated the data. After truncating it started working. But i doubt this problem will come again. Moreover wiping data is not the valid solution

Comment: Truncating is not the solution. This exception comes up whenever there are too many records and you perform a non key filter on it. There isnt a single solution for this, but can be achieved by tuning these (timeout, caching) properties.

Comment: Once you find a working solution, please do update it as an answer.

Comment: Sure @franklinsijo